# Number of linearly independent functions satisfying an nth order homogeneous differential equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

I am considering general solutions to linear differential equations and trying to think of things in terms of linear algebra. I don't think I am quite getting the picture though. In particular, I am reading Riley, Hobson and Bence in which they give the general form of an nth order homgeneous linear differential equation and state that "we must find n linearly independent functions that satisfy it". However I can't quite figure out why this must be so.

My thoughts so far are that:

- If we consider a function space, each application of the derivative operator seems to confine us to a subspace of one less dimension. For instance, if we were to consider any function in terms of it's Taylor expansion (which, since we are differentiation it on some interval, would have to be valid for the differential equations to be a valid one), then when we first apply the derivative operator we eliminate the constant term, and then x to the power 1 etc. Each of these powers of x is clearly linearly independent. (I can't motivate how the derivative operator confines us to a hyperspace in any other way than linking it to the Taylor series though. I can't imagine how it could be the case say for trig or exponential functions, other than by considering Taylor series).
- So clearly the genral solution to $\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}=0$ would have n linearly independent functions that solve it.
- But I am then having trouble extending this to there being lower order derivatives in the homogeneous equation too. Why then do we still need n linearly independent functions as solutions?

Thank you in advance.